# Jquery popup model window like mydala.com

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and web-development. I am just learning it. For my personnel use i need a subscription popup window like in http://www.mydala.com/.

Here the popup appear only once for the particular user unless he close the site.

Please Help me, How i need to do.

Comment: where do you have a pop up in that site?

Comment: after the site completed its loading, popup window will appear for subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the source of that website you'll see it's using the [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and modify css acording to your use

(or) try this plugin http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duXbZ/)**

Comment: thnks for that.Just to help the newguys.

Comment: This is a simple jquery popup, But it is not the one that i am looking for.

Comment: @user1369560-Updated with a new lightbox plugin.And if you search google for lightbox you'll find plenty of them.But we have to change it according to our convinience.

Comment: I have created the popup. Thnx a lot for your Answers

Answer (score 0):

check this site http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/. it shows how to create a dialog box using Jquery. I am using this dialog in my project and i didn't face any issues with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created it